# Finding class by name fails and GetMethod call throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

I have my DLL:

```
using System;
namespace DLLtest
{
    public static class TestDll
    {
        public static void TestVoid()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestVoid called");
        }
    }
}
```

and in my program I'm doing:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(
     Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DLLtest.dll"));
var b = a.GetType("TestDll").GetMethod("TestVoid");
b.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

And I get `NullReferenceException` on "`var b...`" line (indeed something is null as [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) explains, but assembly is loaded and class should be there).

I tried adding BindingFlags, but always the same error...

Comment: I dont think the supposed duplicate question has anything to do with the OP's error here.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso That null reference duplicate gets way overused.

Comment: I think OP will also need to pass `a` as the first arg to the `Invoke` call, or the `Invoke` won't know which object to call the method on. EDIT: this advice is incorrect, method in question example is static.

Comment: @TheGNUGuy or you may want to read on how to call static methods with reflection :)

Answer (score 4):

The name of the type is `DLLTest.TestDll` - so there you get `null` searching for just `TestDll`.

Fix:

- use full class name
- get all types from assembly and find type by matching part of the name.

Comment: He is searching for `DLLTest.dll` and not `TestDll`

Comment: Oh, that's the problem...  
  
Thank you :)

Comment: @RafaelCardoso OP is *loading* "DLLTest.dll" (which should work fine assuming DLL in app's folder, also it throws if you can't load DLL), but `GetType("TestDll")` should fail due to using partial class name.

Comment: Got it. Nice explanation